# SqlCommandBuilder not assigning ConnectionString

Tags: .net, sql-server, gridview, devexpress, datasource

I'm using a devexpress XtraGrid in layout view to edit a recently created database row.
This is the code I use to load data:

```
Public Function SetData(ByVal connString As String, ByVal tabla As String) As Boolean
    Dim d As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn

            m_Tabla = tabla
            If (m_Id = "") Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & m_Tabla
            Else
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & m_Tabla & " WHERE IdCaptura = '" & m_Id & "'"
            End If

            m_Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            m_DataSet = New DataSet()
            m_Adapter.Fill(m_DataSet, m_Tabla)

            grdMetadata.DataSource = m_DataSet.Tables(m_Tabla)
            Return True
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The database can be different from client to client, so AFAIK I can't write the update command; I've been investigating the issue and my conclusion was that I need to use a SqlCommandBuilder to get it automatically generated.

When the user ends editing data, I use the following snippet to update the database:

```
Private Sub btnAceptar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAceptar.Click
    Try
        Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(m_Adapter)

        grdLayoutView.CloseEditor()
        grdLayoutView.UpdateCurrentRow()
        m_Adapter.Update(m_DataSet, m_Tabla) *

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblEstado.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

In the line marked with *, I get a "The ConnectionString Property has not been initialized" exception. The table has a Primary Key column (IdCaptura), and I can see that the DataAdapter.UpdateCommand is set to nothing if I put a breakpoint in said line.

Any idea about what's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time your second code snippet is called, the SqlConnection you made in the first one has been disposed of, per the `using` statement.  That's why it's not initialized.  You're going to have to either not dispose of the connection there, or create another connection for your second code snippet.

Like this, for example:

```
Private Sub btnAceptar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAceptar.Click
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString) ' <--- need to get the connection string from somewhere here '
            conn.Open()
            m_Adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = conn
            Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(m_Adapter)

            grdLayoutView.CloseEditor()
            grdLayoutView.UpdateCurrentRow()
            m_Adapter.Update(m_DataSet, m_Tabla) *
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblEstado.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you say makes some sense, but the SqlDataAdapter doesn't have a Connection property. The DataTable class has one, but I'm not sure how to get one from the adapter... I'll keep looking into this...

Comment: Well, not disposing the connection (i.e., removing the using clause) it works, but I wonder if it's a good idea. I guess at least I should keep a reference to dispose it as soon as I know I won't need it anymore...

Comment: Ah, right.  I should have checked the documentation on SqlDataAdapter.  Well, that's the reason you're getting the uninitialized error.  The connection is getting disposed.  I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Note that if the connection is closed before update or fill is called, the connection is automatically opened, the operation happens, and then the connection is closed again.  Calling conn.Open() isn't actually necessary.  So you can keep an instance of the connection around, if you leave it in a closed state.

Comment: Oh, great, thank you very much. Could you put there a link where the automatic open/close is documented? I have tested that it works, but can't find any mention of it in the documentation of the DataAdapter.